# Updating Table in SQL using DataTables in C#

Tags: c#, database, datatable

I am trying to update a Table in an existing SQL Database while I am using DataTables, DataAdapter and SqlCommandBuilder.

Here is my Update/Synch method:

```cs
   public bool synchSqlData(DataTable UpdateTable)
            {
                bool success = false;
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                using (SqlCommandBuilder cmb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da))
                {
                    da.UpdateCommand = cmb.GetUpdateCommand();
                    try
                    {
                        da.Update(UpdateTable);
                        success = true;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Error has occured!" + ex.Message);
                    }
                }
                return success;
            }
```

And here is my Button_Click event:

```cs
private void btnSynchDB1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tbl1.Merge(tblCmp);
            if (success = sql1.synchSqlData(tbl1))
                MessageBox.Show("Synchronisieren von DB1 erfolgreich!");
        }
```

I am merging two DataTables and then want to update it to my SQL DB.
sql1 contains an SQL Connection.

My SQL DB though is not taking any changes at all.
What am I missing/doing wrong?

***EDIT***

Ok so now I edited to have my DataAdapter initialized with a dynamic Select Command and when im Debugging it I see Insert, Delete and Update command in my DataAdapter that was built by my CommandBuilder. Still there are no changes made to my DB. Why is that?

```
public bool synchSqlData(DataTable UpdateTable, DataTable MergeTable, string selectedTableName, SqlConnection sqlCon)
    {
        bool success = false;
        SqlCommand sqlCom = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo." + selectedTableName, sqlCon);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCom);
        SqlCommandBuilder cmb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);

        da.InsertCommand = cmb.GetInsertCommand();
        da.DeleteCommand = cmb.GetDeleteCommand();
        da.UpdateCommand = cmb.GetUpdateCommand();

        UpdateTable.Merge(MergeTable);

        try
        {
            da.Update(UpdateTable);
            success = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error has occured!" + ex.Message);
            success = false;
        }
        return success;
    }
```

Comment: Have you traced execution of your program with SQL Profiler? Does any command executed at SQL server?

Comment: There is no SQL statement in your Adapter. It is not possible for the command builder to build a valid command.

Comment: I have not. I am reading about it right now(didn't know it before) and will let you know of the result!

Comment: @Steve I added SQL Select Statement to my Adapter still CommandBuilder isnt giving -Insert- or -delete- commands. Why is that?

Comment: Did you have a primary key defined for your table?

Comment: @Steve I updated my Code again, DataAdapter now has alle the commands when I debug it, yet on da.Update() nothing happens to my SQL DB..  How to define a primary key for my table? Do you mean as in my SQL table or my DataTable?  Here is the "InsertCommand" the CommandBuilder has built for example, just to show you:    `"INSERT INTO [dbo].[BacNetRemoteCommands] ([Name], [Enabled], [InstanceNumber], [RefreshConfiguration], [RemoteDevice]) VALUES (@p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5)"`

Comment: @Steve alright I just checked it, yes I have a Primary Key defined for my table. In this Case it is "Name".

Comment: The Update method returns the number of rows modified by the method. Could you confirm that the return value from this method is zero? If it is zero and you don't get any exception then you don't have any row modified to be updated (check if you call AcceptChanges before reaching this method, also consider the behavior of the Merge method on the modified rows) Instead if you have a return value bigger than zero then you are updating something, but probably not the database that you are looking at (check the connectionstring used and the presence of |DataDirectory| substitution string)

Comment: @Steve Wow, so finally I found the reason why it didn't update, took me quite some time.. The problem was the Merge method. It didn't mark any of the Rows in "changed" state even though it adds a lot of rows obviously, they really should overwork that method to change the row's state. Because of that the Update method couldn't see what was changed of course and so didn't do anything..

Comment: Merge has an overload that allows you to control how to treat the changed rows coming from the to be merged table

Comment: @Steve I just added this:                 `foreach (DataRow dr in MergeTable.Rows)
            {
                dr.SetAdded();
            }` before I merge the tables and now it updates the new rows just fine to my SQL DB :)) Thanks a lot for your help/advice and thought-provoking impulses Steve!! Now I can enjoy my weekend, have a good one! :)

Comment: @Steve so I guess if I call Merge method like this `UpdateTable.Merge(MergeTable, false);` it should just do the same thing right? All the time I spent.. and all that was missing was a little "false".. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was the Merge method.

Either call:
`foreach (DataRow dr in MergeTable.Rows) { dr.SetAdded(); }`
before calling .Merge

or just call .Merge like this:
`UpdateTable.Merge(MergeTable, false);`

so that .Update method will reckognize changed rows and Insert/Delete/Update properly.